# Wishlist for guest in cart page not working shows "The requested cart item doesn\'t exist.'" in magento 2

Tags: cart, magento2.2.2, wishlist

I have added wishlist icon on cart page, If customer clicks the icon , it works fine and moved the product to the wishlist.

If the guest tries to click wishlist icon, I have triggered login popup, and forced the customer to logged in.
After the logged in by guest(Now they became customers), But failed to move the products to the wish list,It shows error like

> 'The requested cart item doesn\'t exist.'

Please provide me a solution

Comment: What guest wishlist extension which you used? We using [http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/customer-experience/guest-wishlist-for-magento-2.html](http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/customer-experience/guest-wishlist-for-magento-2.html)